# Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 18 file: Code.gs

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to link the results from a google form for booking devices at my school to a google calendar.

I keep getting this error:

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 18 file: Code.gs

but I can't figure it out.

Please help

```
function bookDevices() {
    
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B5:F100").getValues();
     
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
    
    var shift = signups[x];
   
    var whatDevice = shift[0];
    var whatDate = shift[1];
    var yearGroup = shift[2];
    var startTime = shift[3];
    var endTime = shift[4];
    eventCal.createEvent(title: whatDevice, startTime:whatDate, endTime: whatDate, options: yearGroup);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with scripts in google sheets, but are you sure it supports named parameters? Like `eventCal.createEvent(title: ..., startTime: ...)`? The docs suggest otherwise: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options This should probably be only `eventCal.createEvent(whatDevice, whatDate, whatDate, yearGroup);`

Comment: Try commenting out that line. Your code will not work but is the error still there? - then the real error is elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

There should be pass 4 parameter in createEvent function.
See below link for reference.
Click [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))